# Query from 2 tables in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in MySQL:

Table 1

```
Week    From         Until
1    2015-04-01    2015-04-07
2    2015-04-08    2015-04-14
3    2015-04-15    2015-04-21
4    2015-04-22    2015-04-28
```

Table 2

```
Input_Date        Code
2015-04-10        123
2015-04-22        456
2015-04-25        123
2015-04-26        123
```

1. I used this query to select the current week based on the current date:

   SELECT `Week` FROM `table_1` WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN `From` AND `Until`)
2. I need to select the "code" and count it from table 2 where "Code" = 123 and "Input_Date" corresponds to the current "Week".

*If the current date is 2015-04-23, the "Week" would be = 4

The result would be:

```
Week   Code  Count
 4     123     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try-

```
SELECT t1.Week, t2.Code, COUNT(*) 
FROM table_1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
ON t2.Input_Date BETWEEN t1.From AND t1.Until
WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN t1.From AND t1.Until) 
AND t2.Code = 123
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d2a6/16

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way of doing the same thing without LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT a.week, b.code, count(a.week) 
FROM table_1 a, table_2 b
WHERE (b.input_date BETWEEN a.from AND a.until)
AND (NOW() BETWEEN a.From AND a.Until)
AND b.code = 123
```